# Cardinality of the union of disjoint set, each of which have a cardinality of $\aleph_{0}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider three sets $A$,
  $B$, and
  $C$
  such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$
 , $A\cap C=\emptyset$
 , $B\cap C=\emptyset$
  ($A,B,C$
  are pairwise disjoint) and $\overline{\overline{A}}=\overline{\overline{B}}=\overline{\overline{C}}=\aleph_{0}$
  (i.e. each set has a cardinality of $\aleph_{0}$). What is the cardinality of $A\cup B\cup C$? I feel like it should be $\aleph_{2}$, but every book I have read so far on transfinite arithmetic, perhaps necessarily, makes this question look overly complicated. Thanks.

Comment: Let $ A$ be the integers $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $B$ the integers $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and $C$ the integers $\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Comment: Why do you feel it should be $\aleph_2$? Do you understand the definitions of the $\aleph$ numbers, or are you just guessing because it's a union of three sets?

Comment: I'm sorry. This comment doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Honestly, I was thinking since the closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ is $\Bbb{R}$, and $\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ is the set of irrational numbers, then immediately next to each rational number there is a irrational number, thus for each $q\in\Bbb{Q}$ There are two irrational, so There are $\aleph_1$ irrationals.

Comment: Sorry im usung an iPad it is a bit tricky

Comment: (1) The cardinality of the real numbers, and the irrational numbers as well, is **not** $\aleph_1$. (2) There is no rational "immediately next to". The concept of "immediately next to" doesn't exist in the real numbers. (3) I still can't see your thought process as for why this is going to have cardinality $\aleph_2$ of all cardinalities.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I thought if there are $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ irrational numbers none of which are common with the rational numbers, then when you add back all the rational numbers to get the real number you would end up with a larger infinity (which I thought was $\aleph_2$), so then the cardinality of the real numbers would be $\aleph_2$ as suspected by  Godel (even though he retracted this belief eventually).

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, this was my thought process, but if you read the conversation in the comments of Brian's answers he set me straight. I see the flaws of my thought process now.

Comment: Okay then. Just to point it out, the exact value of $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be decided by the usual axioms of set theory, however the cardinality of the irrational numbers is always that of the real numbers $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am still very new to all of these new ideas, thanks for pointing this out I will keep it in mind! Have a great day I got to get going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s simply $\aleph_0$: the union of three countable sets, whether pairwise disjoint or not, is countable, and if at least one of the sets is infinite, the union is countably infinite.

Suppose, for instance, that $f_A:\Bbb N\to A$, $f_B:\Bbb N\to B$, and $f_C:\Bbb N\to C$ are bijections. Define

$$f:\Bbb N\to A\cup B\cup C:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
f_A\left(\frac{n}3\right),&\text{if }n\equiv 0\pmod 3\\\\
f_B\left(\frac{n-1}3\right),&\text{if }n\equiv 1\pmod 3\\\\
f_C\left(\frac{n-2}3\right),&\text{if }n\equiv 2\pmod 3\;;
\end{cases}$$

it’s not hard to check that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks! (It doesn't make sense to me but though).

Comment: @Jimmy: You’re welcome! Perhaps the explicit bijection that I just added will help a little.

Comment: The bijection you add definetly helps, but my intuition of infinity seems to fail me a little.

Comment: could there exist two distinct irrational numbers which are side by side (The don't have a rational number between them)?

Comment: @Jimmy: If $A$ is an infinite set, and for each $a\in A$ you have a set $A_a$ of the same cardinality as $A$, then $\bigcup_{a\in A}A_a$ also has the same cardinality as $A$. In particular, a countable union of countable sets is countable. This is one of the fundamental differences between infinite and finite sets, so it’s likely to be a sticking point for your intuition. You should start right away trying to beat it into your intuition! `:-)`

Comment: @Jimmy: No: between any two distinct real numbers, rational or irrational, there are infinitely many rational numbers (and infinitely many irrational numbers).

Comment: hahaha Thanks I will try convince myself of this ASAP! It will likely save a lot of headaches :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11689/discussion-between-jimmyjackson-and-brian-m-scott)